# How to add a mailto link or button to modern sharepoint page

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-pages, links

I am trying to add a mailto link or button to a modern SharePoint online page. I want such that when the link is clicked, it will launch Microsoft Outlook or the email client. I have tried using the quick links web part but it is not accepting the link (mailto:myemail@domain.com). It seems to be expecting a link that must start with https://

I would like to know if there are other options I can use to achieve my goal.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, this did not work for me.

Comment: As mentioned by the second responder, this can only be achieved using a text web part. That is what I ended up using. The link and quick links web parts don't allow for non-https links. Hopefully Microsoft will make adjustments in the future.

Comment: This does not allow for providing mailto: links. It auto redirects to https://

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow below steps to add Hyperlinks on your Modern(Site) Pages:

1. Go to your page and Select `Edit` page from right top corner.
2. Click on `+` (to add new web part) from section where you want to add hyperlink.
3. Select `Text` web part from `Text, media, and content` section:

   [image]
4. Then select `Hyperlink` option in the text box web part or just click `Ctrl+K` inside text box web part:

   [image]
5. Provide `mailto:myemail@domain.com` in `Address` and Display text in `Text to display`.
6. Click `Save` button at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **a normal text block** to include a mailto link, as both the Link and Quick Links parts don't allow non-http(s) links. Add the text web part to the section. Don't add a link, instead type `mailto://name@domain.com` then hit enter, it will turn to a link. You may edit the display text using hyperlink menu item on the text web part toolbar to change the display txt to remove the mailto:// without it adding an unwanted https://

[image]